# Is there any work around to get Graph API reports anonymized data ("DisplayName,"URL","UserPrincipalName") with privacy setting enabled.?

Tags: pnp-powershell, onedrive-for-business, azure-ad-graph-api, azureadapps

We are generating custom report for all the onedrive users storage data using Graph API("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOneDriveUsageAccountDetail").

We are able to get this report data but the only issue  is few properties("DisplayName,"URL","UserPrincipalName") within the  report is showing anonymous data due to this privacy settings("Display concealed") enabled in reports setting in tenant.

We can see the valid data(without any code change) on those same reports if we disable this settings.
Unfortunately ,we can't disable this setting as client has some  security concerns.

Queries
1.Is there a way that we can get this anonymous data using some other Graph API .?
2.Is it possible with any other powershell which should be used with Azure AD Approach("Application Permission") but without admin center access..?